# When I start see this massege I want start normal with out this black screen

Tags: startup

*emphasized text* UBUNTU:

clean,

250477/60669952

files,

17953521/242661888

blocks

Comment: A normal message that says there are no problems in said partition. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: How I start normal

Comment: Please edit the question and describe what's happening, your Ubuntu release/version and hardware specifications.

Comment: I can't start normal how I can start with out this massege

Comment: That message IS normal whether you see it or not. That's NOT the problem. Please read the previous comment and act accordingly.

Comment: How I finish this massege and open my laptop normal with out this black screen